# How to get value from the URL

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Thease days, I study about WebRTC from https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab
But, I have some problem at step5.
I can't resolve step5 bonus points number 5. Question is this : ***This app uses a JavaScript prompt to get a room name. Work out a way to get the room name from the URL, for example localhost:2013/foo would give the room name foo.***

I used javascript window.location.pathname, but it didn't work. 
If you help me, I very appreciate it!

Comment: how did it not work? If you do not supply the room, then of course it will not be there...

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Thank you for your advice. Actually, I'm not good well in English. So, it's hard to explain in detail to me. Anyway, I want to resolve step 5. Bonus points 5. I don't know how to get room name from URL. I did location.pathname, below suggetion, but only localhost:2013/index.html was work! When I did that, room name was index.html. am.. I'm sorry, I cant' english well. So, I wonder if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Did you actually set up rooms? You cannot get the room names unless there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var str = window.location.href;
var path = str.split('/');
var value = path[path.length-1]; //foo
```

Comment: NO.. it didn't work. I already try this. Browser can't find localhost:2013/foo page. It occur 404 error. Could you recommend other thing?

Comment: @ybin, you don't mention a 404 error anywhere in your question, how do you expect helpful answers if you do not ask the right question?

Answer (score 0):

pathname actually works.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            alert(window.location.pathname);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
var aarr = window.location.href.split('/');
//get last value
var id = aarr[aarr.length -1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastIndexOf` since you're only concerned about getting one element instead of using split which would return all of them.

```
var url = "http://localhost:2013/foo";
console.log(url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)); // returns 'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you about your comment! BUt I mean how to get from the "browser's URL"